# publish iphone app that requires user to register

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ipod

I created iPhone app that requires the user to register and log in before open the app. 
This application has been rejected from App Store and they gave me this message:

> We found that your app requires customers to register with personal
>   information to access non-account-based features, which is not in
>   compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Apps cannot require user registration prior to allowing access to app
>   features and content  that are not associated specifically to the
>   user. User registration that requires the sharing of personal
>   information must be optional or tied to account-specific
>   functionality. Additionally, the requested information must be
>   relevant to the features.

I payed all my efforts and time in this app. So, my question is: Is there is any Solution to make the App Store accept my app without changing anything in its structure ??

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Make the neccessary changes to the app.
2. Contact Apple, and explain why your application needs the user to register, and that the application is indeed in compliance with the rules.

Option 2 works best if the application actually conforms to the rules, but depending on what the app actually does, there might be a grey area. Unfortunately the outcome of this option can also be closely correlated to communication skills - so prepare your arguments before calling or mailing Apple.

Comment: Ok, this means that its best to change my app. Thanks so much for your answer.